# Where can I find the articles in the Joomla File System?

Tags: joomla

I have a webpage created by Joomla, and I can see its file system by FTP.
I see a lot of folders, but I don't know where can I find the articles's contents (the text).
My webpage doesn't work because of a SQL error, and I can't login the administrator page, but I want to download the contents of the articles of the webpage.

Comment: The articles are stored in the database, not files. Look for the table `#__content`

Comment: Sad. They were in the DB, as Lodder stated. Ask your hosting for the DB backup... Can you access the DB itself through for example PHPMyAdmin? Is the content still there?

Comment: What was the database error?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm,as stated, the Joomla "Articles" are database content so you wont find the equivalent of html "files" for each article in your ftp folders sadly. However, even though there has been a sql error, there is still a chance that you can access the DB tables to read your database through phpmyadmin as suggested. If not, assuming that your site has been around long enough to be fully indexed by google, you should still be able to get hold of the text for your articles through Google's cache - at least that way you can copy and paste the text from your old articles into notepad giving you a reference and saving you having to retype or rewrite them. Read more on Google Cache here http://www.googleguide.com/cached_pages.html